# How can we see when query store in SQL Server 2016 was turned ON and OFF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-query-store

Is there a way to query and find when the query store in a SQL Server 2016 database was turned ON and OFF? Like an audit log...

I need to query the query store for specific periods over the last year. But it has been turned ON and OFF multiple times. So I'm looking if there is a log like this that can help me

| Query Store Operation Mode | DateTimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| OFF | 1/7/2023 00:30 |
| READ WRITE | 2/7/2023 20:00 |
| OFF | 17/7/2023 15:55 |
| READ ONLY | 21/7/2023 20:22 |
| OFF | 01/8/2023 19:23 |

Comment: TBH I would have assumed that when you turn off QueryStore it would also clear any resources used by it - if you want to see what time intervals it contains you can query  `sys.query_store_runtime_stats_interval`